# Adding Data from a Database to a dataGridView -- C# / SQL Server (Staff Rota)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datagridview

Sample data:

```
Id | Name       |   DOB     | TEL         | Address        | WDays   | DateInWork
---+------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------+---------------
 2 | Conall B   |1999-10-20 | 07654227534 | 1 Made up Road | Sun-Wed | 2020-04-12
 2 | Conall B   |1999-10-20 | 07654227534 | 1 Made up Road | Sun-Wed | 2020-05-11
 3 | Michael J  |1999-10-19 | 07755428737 | 15 Made up St  | Sun-Wed | 2020-04-12
 4 | Kuba R     |1992-04-11 | 07654421231 | 7 Made up Aven | Sun-Wed | 2020-04-12
 8 | Connor T   |1994-07-23 | 07628395102 | 9 Made up Garde| Sun-Wed | 2020-04-12
11 | Harry G    |1997-12-31 | 07676192327 |19 Made up St   | Sun-Wed | 2020-04-12
```

This data is returned when this command is executed:

```
SELECT 
    s.*, b.DateOfEvent 
FROM 
    Staff s, Booking b, BookingStaff bs 
WHERE 
    bs.StaffId = s.StaffId 
    AND bs.BookingId = b.BookingId  
    AND b.DateOfEvent BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '12/12/2020'
```

As you can see there are 3 tables involved. A Booking Table, A Staff Table and A BookingStaff Table. The booking has a 1 - M relationship with the BookingStaff and the Staff also has a 1 - M with the BookingStaff.
Ok so on the UI I wish to adapt this data from its current state - as shown in the sample data section to a more user friendly state. Basically the datagridview will contain columns ranging from Monday - Sunday. And the rows header values will Be the Staffid/Name/Age. 
My code so far is as follows:

```
SqlCommand Staff = new SqlCommand("SELECT s.*, b.DateOfEvent FROM Staff s, Booking b, BookingStaff bs WHERE bs.StaffId = s.StaffId AND bs.BookingId = b.BookingId AND b.DateOfEvent BETWEEN '" + Convert.ToDateTime(startDate) + "' AND '" + Convert.ToDateTime(endDate) + "'", c);

        c.Open();
        List<string> staffids = new List<string>();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = Staff.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                string staffId = Convert.ToString(reader["StaffId"]);

                string Name = Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]) +" " + Convert.ToString(reader["Surname"]);
                DateTime DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DOB"]);
                string Age = Convert.ToString(((DateTime.Today.Year * 100 + DateTime.Today.Month) * 100 + DateTime.Today.Day) - ((DOB.Year * 100 + DOB.Month) * 100 + DOB.Day));
                string DaysInWork = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateOfEvent"]).Day.ToString();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if(!staffids.Contains(staffId))
                    {
                        row.HeaderCell.Value = "Staff ID: " + staffId + "\n" + "Name:" + Name + "\n" + "Age:" + Age; 
                    }

                }
                staffids.Add(staffId);
            }
        }
        c.Close();
```

The current issue I'm having is inserting the data into the correct place. Ok so say I have 5 people assigned to a booking on a Monday. Then 5 cells of the Monday will fill up. But then say 1 of those 5 also works on the tuesday of that week how do I then insert this data into the Tuesday? Any help would be appreciated. I'm sorry in advance if this, at all was poorly explained. Heres an image of what I'm going for: https://rotacloud-website.s3.amazonaws.com/v2/img/pages/home/product-ss.png

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: first question...how is dataGridView1.Rows already populated with your list of employees?  i assume you want to find the matching row for your record instead of doing an n^2 loop...instead of using the grid...the underlying source of datagridview1 should have a data source with a key on it...and find the employee's row and update it

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I see what you mean but I didnt see the point in having staff listed that weren't working for that week. But yes i want to search for the record after i populate the rowheader with the staff details. The code that adds the staff to the record is within the foreach loop. Maybe i'm misunderstanding your question but i think that should explain it.